# Quotient rule - Different calculus application

Tags: calculus

$$h(x) = \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$

$$h'(x) = \frac{f'(x)}{g(x)}$$

$$f(x)<0$$

$$g(5) = 2$$

I am trying to figure out what $g(x)$ would be.

When I use the quotient rule, I get:

$$f(x)\times \frac{g'(x)}{g(x)} = 0$$

This would mean that I cannot determine the value of $g(x)$, no?

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks :)

These are the possible solutions given to me:

1. $$\frac{1}{f'(x)}$$
2. $${f(x)}$$
3. $${-f(x)}$$
4. $${0}$$

Comment: I think you're on the right track when using the quotient rule, but I also believe you made a mistake when using it. Check your work- you should be getting f(x)*g'(x) = 0.

Comment: $$h=\frac fg\implies h'=\frac{f'g-fg'}{g^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

You can use $f(x)=h(x)g(x)$ along with the product rule to deduce that
$$
f'(x)=h'(x)g(x)+g'(x)h(x)\implies 0=g'(x)h(x)=g'(x)f(x)/g(x)\implies g'(x)=0
$$
because $f(x)<0$. So $g(x)$ is constant. With $g(5)=2$, we infer that $g$ is 2 everywhere.

**Edit**: Now suppose that we have to select one of the 4 choices you are given.

**Choice 4**: incorrect because then division by $g$ wouldn't make sense.

**Choice 2**: incorrect because $f<0$ whereas $g=2$.

**Choice 1**: suppose this one was true, then $g=2=\frac{1}{f'}$ so $f'=\frac{1}{2}$ which would imply $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}x+C$. But $\frac{1}{2}x+C$ cannot be always be negative so we'd have a contradiction.

**Choice 3**: this remaining possibility is the only consistent one. Take $f(x)=-2$, $g(x)=2$, and $h(x)=-1$.

Comment: I am not sure what am I am missing, but these are the options given to me:                                                1/f'(x)                                                   
f(x)
-f(x)
0

Comment: Choices 2-3 are incorrect because in those 2 cases $h$ is just constant whereas $f'$ isn't necessarily $0$. Choice 4 is nonsensical because you have to divide by $g$. For choice 1, try $f(x)=\frac{1}{a}(\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}-2)$ where $a>0$ is a scaling factor to ensure that $g(5)=2$. Perhaps, a misprint?

Comment: @ OP: last night, perhaps I misunderstood the question. Please see edit.